# WCF MaxReceivedMessageSize not working correctly (not being read)

Tags: wcf, exception, maxreceivedmessagesize

I have a WCF service in which I'm trying to pull out a certain XML file, and send this file to the client, but I keep getting this error:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

I have changed the `maxReceivedMessageSize` in my app.config.

**App.config**

***Endpoint configuration***

```
<services>
  <service name="MobileReportService.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/MobileReportService/Service/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint name="ServiceEndpoint"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="MobileReportService.IService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

***Binding configuration***

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" maxBufferSize="5242880"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I don't quite understand why the `maxReceivedMessageSize` can't be read?

### Edit

I'm testing the service through the popup that appears whenever I run the service, by pressing "Invoke"

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the binding name. There is no need to define a binding name unless you are defining more than one basicHttpBinding configuration. If you remove the name the defined settings will apply to all endpoints using the binding type.

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="(big number)" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Check the main question edit. This is where I test, so there's not really a client side. This is made on the server side

Comment: @Detilium did you remove the binding name (binding1)?

Comment: You can edit the configuration file for the WCF Test Client.  Right-Click on the Config File node in the left pane and select Edit with ScvConfigEditor.

Comment: @TomRedfern - maxReceivedMessageSize only applies to service or the client (depending on which config file you're talking about).  Setting an increased maxReceivedMessageSize on the service side will not help if the response from the service is to large for the client to consume.

Comment: @TomRedfern Yes I did.

Comment: @Tim thanks for your comment. So if I understand correctly, you're saying that maxReceivedMessageSize is a client-side setting only and is ignored on the service-side?

Comment: @TomRedfern - Close.  It's an application-specific setting. In other words, if it's in the client's config file, it applies to the client.  If it's in the service's config file, it applies to the service.

Comment: @Tim - so what would happen if the client had maxReceivedMessageSize  = 50KB and the service had it set to 10KB, and then the service sends a 25KB response to the client? Would that work because in this instance the client has a sufficient threshhold set? If the the client then sent a 25KB request then would it fail because the service threshold is violated? I know I should set a test up for this...

Comment: @TomRedfern - Yes, you have the right of it.   It's simple to test - I discovered this in my early days of WCF development (back in 2010-2011) when I had a service that was failing due to the error.  I only had to change the client's settings.  Generally speaking most people use the exact same binding configuration's for client and service (partly convenience, though a lot of the values must match), but in this case it's not strictly necessary (and to prevent DDOS and similar attacks it's probably better not to).

Comment: @Tim OK thanks I have adjusted my answer accordingly

Comment: Remove binding name worked for me!!  So my question is, what binding does the service use then?